# CrossDomain WCF consumed by jQuery JSONP returns undefined

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf, iis-7, jsonp

Credit to Pranay Rana for this example:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/223572/Calling-Cross-Domain-WCF-service-using-Jquery-Java

Having an issue where it fails here with link to actual WCF:
http://jsfiddle.net/TyrHW/

Markup:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WCF1.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory"%>
```

C# WCF Service

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace WCF1
{
        [DataContract]
        public class Customer
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string Name;

            [DataMember]
        public string Address;


        }


  [ServiceContract(Namespace = "JsonpAjaxService")]
  [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =   AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]

    public class Service1
    {
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public Customer GetCustomer()
        {
            return new Customer() { Name = "Jacob Pines", Address = "999 S William St." };
        }
    }
    }
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"  />

    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel >
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
            <standardEndpoints>
                <webScriptEndpoint>
                        <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/>
                </webScriptEndpoint>
            </standardEndpoints>


    </system.serviceModel>


    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

    </system.webServer>

    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>


</configuration>
```

I get the same result locally as in my godaddy .net 4.0 host.  I've checked asp.net levels.  IIS security at goddady is set to annonymous. If I enter the url to the Service in a browser I get some apparent issue with authentication which I've sent to Godaddy. If I do the same locally, I get what appears to healthy Web Service, though still get undefined from jsFiddle.

It's all new to me .. so It's been a mission.
Thanks.

Comment: I would refrain from JSONP as it poses a security risk IMHO...

Comment: I would be interested in Client code alternatives. It needs to be WCF as I need to consume it from SharePoint 365 Online.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from the [following article](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2008/02/calling-wcf-service-from-javascript.html):

> This all works fine when running it in Cassini, but when you want to
>   host it in IIS, you will need to take care two things. First, you will
>   need to ensure that IIS and WCF are correctly installed and
>   registered. If IIS does not seem to want to cough up your SVC files
>   (you can check that by trying http:////AjaxService.svc), try running the command ServiceModelReg.exe /i
>   /x from %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication
>   Foundation. Restart IIS after running this command. Second, if you
>   created a default ASP.NET 2.0 website, you may run into this error
>   message:
>
> `IIS specified authentication schemes
>   'IntegratedWindowsAuthentication, Anonymous', but the binding only
>   supports specification of exactly one authentication scheme. Valid
>   authentication schemes are Digest, Negotiate, NTLM, Basic, or
>   Anonymous. Change the IIS settings so that only a single
>   authentication scheme is used.`
>
> To fix this, right-click the website in
>   your IIS manager and choose "properties". Then click the "Directory"
>   tab, click the "Edit" button in the "Anonymous access and
>   authentication control" area. You will see that both Anonymous access
>   and Integrated Windows Authentication are selected. Unselect one of
>   them, then restart IIS. After that, the application should work
>   smoothly.

In your case replace Integrated Windows Authentication with Basic Authentication.

Comment: I just tested it on my local IIS and works perfectly. I'm not sure I have that much control over IIS on my Godaddy host I only see these 3 options in their IIS Manager x-Anonymous Access, Directory Browsing, x-Set Application Root and anon and set root are turned on. I've opened a ticket with a link back to this post. Thank You.

Comment: Just tried turning off Anonymous switch in Godaddy IIS manager for the application folder.. same issue.  I see a Pipeline setting with options for classic and integrated. Not sure security is gonna work as I don't have accounts with them.  Setting Anonymous back on.

Comment: sorry bout play by play.. just so close. Just pointed my router to my client's web port and tried to access with my hostname and it fails with Undefined. set it back to http://localhost:8081 and it works. May be a loopback issue on that test, but does appear to be security related. http://jsfiddle.net/fqZtF/

Comment: locally via host or losthost url, the solution NOW ALWAYS WORKS http://jsfiddle.net/fqZtF/. I was just having a firewall issue. IIS is set to only anonymous and .net 4.0.  At GoDaddy, the solution only produces UNDEFINED per this list jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/TyrHW/